# How to invoke an activity from background services when arrives a notification?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notification-bar, android-intentservice

> I want to check notifications from background receivers or services.
>   The notification is shown, but it should also invoke an activity.

### MainActicityClass

> Here I have created the alarm class which would call broadcast manager at specific interval

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.context = this;
    Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if(alarmRunning == false) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

### Alarm Receiver Class

> This is the broadcast class to invoke from back ground

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AlarmReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, MyListenerServices.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

### MyListener

> This is subclass of notificationlistener services
>   Its reads any incoming notification but unable to read the notification from inactive class
>   Integrate class read any kind of incoming notification from background

```
public class MyListenerServices extends NotificationListenerService{
    public MyListenerServices() {
    }

    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private Thread backgroundThread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something here
            Log.d("MSG", "ServiceRunning");
                     StatusBarNotification[] statusBarNotifications     =    getActiveNotifications();

Log.d("MSG", "New Object2 "+statusBarNotificationsArray);
                if (statusBarNotifications.length > 0) {
                    Log.d("MSG", "New Object "+statusBarNotifications.length);
//
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, AutomaticCameraActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
//                }
//            }catch (Exception e){
//                Log.d("MSG",e.getMessage());
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Notification mNotification=sbn.getNotification();
        Log.v("MSG"," Notification"+ mNotification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

### Any help would be appreciated

> Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar, but you need to add the relevant code: how are you invoking the notification? How are you trying to call the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Create a pending intent

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
//Change ResultActivity by your activity you want invoke
...
// Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
// no need to create an artificial back stack.
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

More information in [Create Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)